# python too fast for gnuplot to complete its work

Tags: python, loops, gnuplot

Altogether with gnuplot and python I have an analysis which briefly may be described as gnuplot accessing the files' statistics, plotting the data, while Python subsequenty shall remove the file for good:

```py
import fnmatch
import os
import sys
import time
import PyGnuplot as gp

register = []
for file in os.listdir("."):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, "*.dat"):
    register.append(file)
register.sort()


def plot_map():
    """ Access statistics (column 3) and plot the map with gnuplot. """
    for entry in register:
    input_file = str(entry)
    output_file = str(entry)[:-4] + str(".png")

    gp.c('input = "{}"'.format(input_file))
    gp.c('set output "{}"'.format(output_file))

    gp.c('stats input u 3')  # place holder

    gp.c('set terminal pngcairo')
    gp.c('set title "{}" noenhanced'.format(input_file))
    gp.c('unset key')

    gp.c('set size square; set pm3 map; set palette cubehelix')
    gp.c('sp input u 1:2:3')

    # For these data, task and allocated computer, gnuplot requires
    # this (empirically estimated) safety margin to complete:
    time.sleep(1)
    os.remove(entry)


plot_map()
sys.exit(0)
```

Typically, multiple dozens of matrices with 50k+ entries each are to be scrunitinzed in one run.  Without the `time.sleep`, estimated by try-and-error, especially on less resourceful computers, however, Python may advance so much faster than gnuplot that eventually there are no data files left for gnuplot to work on.

How may Python's work moderated more efficiently to await gnuplot's task to be completed, and only then to remove the file in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such a case, I would suggest calling `gnuplot` *directly* using `subprocess.run`. When `run` returns, gnuplot has finished.

For [example](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/master/histdata.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# file: histdata.py
# vim:fileencoding=utf-8:fdm=marker:ft=python
#
# Copyright © 2012-2018 R.F. Smith <rsmith@xs4all.nl>.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
# Created: 2012-07-23T01:18:29+02:00
# Last modified: 2019-07-27T13:50:29+0200
"""Make a histogram and calculate entropy of files."""

import math
import os.path
import subprocess as sp
import sys


def main(argv):
    """
    Entry point for histdata.

    Arguments:
        argv: List of file names.
    """
    if len(argv) < 1:
        sys.exit(1)
    for fn in argv:
        hdata, size = readdata(fn)
        e = entropy(hdata, size)
        print(f"entropy of {fn} is {e:.4f} bits/byte")
        histogram_gnuplot(hdata, size, fn)


def readdata(name):
    """
    Read the data from a file and count it.

    Arguments:
        name: String containing the filename to open.

    Returns:
        A tuple (counts list, length of data).
    """
    f = open(name, 'rb')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    ba = bytearray(data)
    del data
    counts = [0] * 256
    for b in ba:
        counts[b] += 1
    return (counts, float(len(ba)))


def entropy(counts, sz):
    """
    Calculate the entropy of the data represented by the counts list.

    Arguments:
        counts: List of counts.
        sz: Length of the data in bytes.

    Returns:
        Entropy value.
    """
    ent = 0.0
    for b in counts:
        if b == 0:
            continue
        p = float(b) / sz
        ent -= p * math.log(p, 256)
    return ent * 8


def histogram_gnuplot(counts, sz, name):
    """
    Use gnuplot to create a histogram from the data in the form of a PDF file.

    Arguments
        counts: List of counts.
        sz: Length of the data in bytes.
        name: Name of the output file.
    """
    counts = [100 * c / sz for c in counts]
    rnd = 1.0 / 256 * 100
    pl = ['set terminal pdfcairo size 18 cm,10 cm']

    pl += ["set style line 1 lc rgb '#E41A1C' pt 1 ps 1 lt 1 lw 4"]
    pl += ["set style line 2 lc rgb '#377EB8' pt 6 ps 1 lt 1 lw 4"]
    pl += ["set style line 3 lc rgb '#4DAF4A' pt 2 ps 1 lt 1 lw 4"]
    pl += ["set style line 4 lc rgb '#984EA3' pt 3 ps 1 lt 1 lw 4"]
    pl += ["set style line 5 lc rgb '#FF7F00' pt 4 ps 1 lt 1 lw 4"]
    pl += ["set style line 6 lc rgb '#FFFF33' pt 5 ps 1 lt 1 lw 4"]
    pl += ["set style line 7 lc rgb '#A65628' pt 7 ps 1 lt 1 lw 4"]
    pl += ["set style line 8 lc rgb '#F781BF' pt 8 ps 1 lt 1 lw 4"]
    pl += ["set palette maxcolors 8"]
    pl += [
        "set palette defined ( 0 '#E41A1C', 1 '#377EB8', 2 '#4DAF4A',"
        " 3 '#984EA3',4 '#FF7F00', 5 '#FFFF33', 6 '#A65628', 7 '#F781BF' )"
    ]
    pl += ["set style line 11 lc rgb '#808080' lt 1 lw 5"]
    pl += ["set border 3 back ls 11"]
    pl += ["set tics nomirror"]
    pl += ["set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 2"]
    pl += ["set grid back ls 12"]
    nm = os.path.basename(name)
    pl += [f"set output 'hist-{nm}.pdf'"]
    pl += ['set xrange[-1:256]']
    pl += ['set yrange[0:*]']
    pl += ['set key right top']
    pl += ['set xlabel "byte value"']
    pl += ['set ylabel "occurance [%]"']
    pl += [f'rnd(x) = {rnd:.6f}']
    pl += [f"plot '-' using 1:2 with points ls 1 title '{name}', "
        f"rnd(x) with lines ls 2 title 'continuous uniform ({rnd:.6f}%)'"]
    for n, v in enumerate(counts):
        pl += [f'{n} {v}']
    pl += ['e']
    pt = '\n'.join(pl)
    sp.run(['gnuplot'], input=pt.encode('utf-8'), check=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**Edit:** As you can see, the above code has a significant history. One thing that I tend to do differently these days is to use inline data (see `help inline` inside gnuplot) in the form of here-documents.

This is more flexible then using the `'-'` file. The data is persistent and can be used in more than one plot.

For example:

```
pl += ['$data << EOD']
pl += [f'{n} {n**2}' for n in range(20)]
pl += ['EOD']
```

Comment: Initially I *speculated* there could be a more explicit signal by gnuplot back to Python about the 'inner work'  (by gnuplot) accomplished.  I like how your approach completing the string of instructions eventually sent to gnuplot uses  the `+=` string addition, which may offer both the flexibility of conditional `if` and `while` clauses as well as comments right in the very corresponding lines.

Comment: Based on the pattern in `def histogram_gnuplot`, I built a loop which works as smooth as hoped provided I skip the instruction of `pl += ['e']` (Python 3.6.9, gnuplot 5.2.7b by 2019-05-14).  The script closes with the CLI prompt accessible directly (without an additional `ENTER` after completion of the batch) ein either Linux, or Windows ecosystem even with files .ge. 5 MB which was not (yet) the case with the other approach.  Different to current Python3, the `os.module` in legacy Python 2.7.17 apparently does not allow the `os.run()` instruction, though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your minimal example is not correct in several ways and does not work right away on my system.

The basic idea of the following script (tested(!) under Windows) is to call a system command within gnuplot. As far as I can tell the full filename seems to be required.
Something special seems to the single quotes and the double quotes. I'm not sure, but I guess gnuplot  requires filename in single quotes whereas the system command (at least in Windows) seems to require the filename in double quotes.

Anyway, at least, the code was working without problems under Windows and creating the plots and deleting the files. In case you work with Linux, I hope you can adapt it accordingly.

**Code:**

```
### generate plots and delete input files
import os
import PyGnuplot as gp

dir_in = r'C:\Test\In'
dir_out = r'C:\Test\Out'

for file in os.listdir(dir_in):
    ffname_in = "'" + os.path.join(dir_in,file) + "'"        # 'full filename_in'
    ffname_del = '"' + os.path.join(dir_in,file) + '"'        # "full filename_del"
    ffname_out = "'" + os.path.join(dir_out,file) + ".pdf'"   # 'full filename_out'
    gp.c('set terminal pdfcairo')
    gp.c('set output ' + ffname_out)
    gp.c('input = ' + ffname_in)
    gp.c('stats input u 2 nooutput')
    gp.c('plot input u 1:2')
    gp.c('set output')
    gp.c('print ' + ffname_in)
    delete_cmd = "system ('del " + ffname_del + "')"
    gp.c(delete_cmd)
### end of code
```

Comment: I agree with you that the question initially deposit did not qualify as MWE.  This, altogether with some edit of the question, was fixed.

Comment: Already because of the «termination signal» `delete_cmd` your approach includes which is triggered from work with gnuplot rather than from the (outer) Python loop over files I equally tested your code on my data in question. Maybe the detail is Windows-only, but with WinPython3 I had to hit ENTER *again* after the last file successfully processed (yielding both the plot, and removing the original `.dat` file, as wanted) by the batch to regain the CLI prompt of `cmd.exe` again.